# Can you nest a unpiped dplyr function inside a piped dplyr function?

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code works fine and returns a data frame that is 5 rows long. Which is exactly what I want.

```
distDF <- as.data.frame(gDistance(kmlIn_sp, fsl_sp, byid = TRUE)) %>% 
                mutate(fslID = row_number()) %>% 
                filter(Col1 < 1000) %>% 
                arrange(Col1)
```

The `fslID` for the first row of the output data frame is `6`.

The following code works just fine on its own and returns the exact value I want from the `fslDF` data frame. It also works for all other `fslID` numbers in the `distDF` data frame created above.

```
filter(fslDF, row_number() == 6)[["TYPE"]]
```

However, when I try to pipe `%>%` the `distDF` data frame into the `mutate` function with the nested `filter` function given just above, like:

```
distDF <- as.data.frame(gDistance(kmlIn, fslDF, byid = TRUE)) %>% 
                mutate(fslID = row_number()) %>% 
                filter(Col1 < 1000) %>% 
                arrange(Col1) %>% 
                mutate(TYPE = filter(fslDF, row_number() == fslID)[["TYPE"]])
```

I get the following:

```
Error: incorrect length (5), expecting: 21
```

`length(distDF)` is 5; and `length(fslDF)` is 21.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Before the first `filter` function, the `distDF` data frame length is 21.  After the first `filter` function, the `distDF` data frame length is 5.  Hence, by the time the code gets to the 2nd `mutate` function, the `distDF` data frame length is 5.   Why is the nested `filter` function at the end looking all the way back to the beginning of the pipe chain for a data frame of length 21?

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible with a small sample data set

Comment: My guess would be `mutate(TYPE = filter(., row_number() == fslID)[["TYPE"]])`. But hard to say without anything reproducible.

Comment: The last filter operates on all rows of that data frame where as your assignment operates on the filtered data frame.